# Filter data.table by condition, but keeping at least one row per N rows

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have this trivial data.table:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  day = 1:10,
  a = c(0, 1, 10, 2, 2.5, 2.3, 2.7, 2.9, 5, 8)
)
```

And I want to filter it according to some condition on `a`. In this case, the moments where `a` changes by more than 3. That much is trivial:

```
dt[abs(a - shift(a)) >= 3]
```

However, I don't want to lose information over long stretches of time. So if there's no hit to the above condition, I need to make sure there's no "filtered-out" stretch greater than 3 days.

In the case above, the condition based on `a` is satisfied by:

```
dt[, abs(a - shift(a)) >= 3]
# [1]    NA FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
                              -----------------------------
```

Notice there's a long stretch of `FALSE` near the end. The best I thought of is

```
dt[, abs(a - shift(a)) >= 3 | .I %% 3 == 0]
# [1]    NA FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
                                     ----              ----
```

(i.e. make sure every third row is accepted) But it doesn't place the best or fewest additional rows.

The optimal outcome would be a filter which breaks that line of `FALSE` with a single `TRUE` right in the middle (or as many as is necessary).

```
# [1]    NA FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
                                          ----
```

Comment: To be robust (catch all occurrences) yet efficient (save only rows that are needed), you will need an iterative approach. (1) filter on the basic condition; (2) for each interval that is "too long", determine your interval based on the preceding and following rows and include those in your logic. Not beautiful, but I don't know if an easy "running logic" that will cover all of your conditions.

Comment: @r2evans I don't think "optimal" interval is needed. Interval is predefined: *"make sure every third (nth) row is accepted"*.

Comment: True, and I was not assuming that all rows are always 1 day separated. (I'm a bit more paranoid and defensive in data-munging, where a lag of 1 row does not always mean a lag of 1 day, perhaps it's same-day or a week different.) Perhaps I'm over-complicating it. (If the OP language instead said *"no filtered-out stretch greater than 3 **rows**"*, then it'd be unambiguous.)

Comment: Similarly, that *"every 3 days"* thing starts at the most-recent "condition-met" row, not necessarily based on "row number modulus 3", as that could introduce more rows than strictly necessary. (Ergo my comment on "robust yet efficient", a careful balance.)

Comment: @r2evans Exactly. My solution of adding the `.I %%3 == 0` condition works in that it makes sure no streak longer than 3 exists. However it isn't very efficient in how it chooses the rows needed to break the streaks, which is precisely why I'm asking this question: to see if there's a better solution.

Comment: Wasabi, is your logic *"no more than 3 rows"* (or `day` is never other than "1" different), or is it really *"3 days"* and `day` can vary by other than 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe someone can replicate this in `data.table` but here's the logic you might be looking for. I separated out `test`, `run_length`, and `result` just for clarity but the logic can be combined or wrapped in a function if needed.

This keeps all the rows where

1. `test` is `TRUE`

   **OR**
2. Every `N`th row in every streak of `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

This way all `TRUE`s are preserved by the first condition and second condition captures every `N`th element of every streak thus capturing some `FALSE`s as well. -

```
library(dplyr)

N <- 3

dt %>% 
  mutate(
    test = abs(a - lag(a)) >= N, # flag change(a) >= N
    run_length = sequence(rle(test)$lengths), # seq along streaks of TRUE and FALSE
    result = test | run_length %% N == 0 
  ) # %>% 
  # filter(result) # uncomment this to get final dt

   day    a  test run_length result
1    1  0.0    NA          1     NA
2    2  1.0 FALSE          1  FALSE
3    3 10.0  TRUE          1   TRUE
4    4  2.0  TRUE          2   TRUE
5    5  2.5 FALSE          1  FALSE
6    6  2.3 FALSE          2  FALSE
7    7  2.7 FALSE          3   TRUE
8    8  2.9 FALSE          4  FALSE
9    9  5.0 FALSE          5  FALSE
10  10  8.0  TRUE          1   TRUE
```

In `data.table` (I guess) -

```
dt[, (test <- abs(a - shift(a)) >= N) | sequence(rle(test)$lengths) %% N == 0]

[1] NA FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: That data.table version works like a charm. Could you just expand on it a bit? I'm having a bit of trouble making sense of it (mostly the `with` statement, since my understand would be that I can rewrite it as `... | sequence(lengths(rle(test))) %% 3 == 0`, but that actually gives a different result). I'd also never seen the use of `<-` in `j` to create a temporary column available in other calculations.

Comment: Upvote for the `rle` solution, that's the concept I was thinking of but didn't wrap my brain around it.

Comment: @Wasabi I edited the answer to remove `with()`. As for the `(test <- ...)` I was under the impression it would create object `test` in global env but apparently it doesn't and yet the code works! I can't say why since I never really use `data.table`. Anyways, I added more explanation and comments to my `dplyr` code to improve logic's clarity. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you really mean

> there's no "filtered-out" stretch greater than 3 ***rows***

then here's a try. Your `abs(a - shift(a))` leaves the first conditional as `NA`, which messes with the `cumsum` step, so we can replace that with one of

```r
c(FALSE, abs(diff(a)) >= 3)
.I > 1 & abs(a - shift(a)) >= 3
abs(a - shift(a, fill = a[1])) >= 3
```

This ensures that the first row is not ignored. For this demo, I'll use the third as it is consistent with your use of `shift`, over to you which you prefer for maintenance.

The challenge is just this: given a vector, identify elements such that the gap between chosen elements is never more than some defined value (3 in this case). Define `no_further` to say "no further `than` so many steps from the previous 'true'". (Perhaps I need to work on the wording of that.)

```r
no_further(4:10, than = 3)      # expect: '7'
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

v <- c(4, 6, 8, 9, 10)
### 4 to 8 is too far, need '6' to be included
### 6 to 8 is good
### 6 to 9 is good, but since 6 to 10 is too far, need '9' to be included
no_further(v, than = 3) # expect: '6', '9'
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

no_further <- function(x, than) {
  i <- 1
  out <- logical(length(x))
  while (i < length(x)) {
    d <- x - x[i]
    if (!is.na(toobig <- which(d > than)[1])) {
      out[ toobig-1 ] <- TRUE
      i <- toobig-1
    } else break
  }
  out
}
```

We can then use this function within each group of the data (a group defined as starting from another condition):

```r
library(magrittr) # solely for demo with %>% pipes, not needed for the function
dt %>%
  .[, keep := abs(a - shift(a, fill = a[1])) >= 3 ] %>%
  .[, grp1 := cumsum(keep) ] %>%
  .[, keep2 := keep | no_further(day, than = 3), by = "grp1" ]
#     day    a  keep grp1 keep2
#  1:   1  0.0 FALSE    0 FALSE
#  2:   2  1.0 FALSE    0 FALSE
#  3:   3 10.0  TRUE    1  TRUE
#  4:   4  2.0  TRUE    2  TRUE
#  5:   5  2.5 FALSE    2 FALSE
#  6:   6  2.3 FALSE    2 FALSE
#  7:   7  2.7 FALSE    2  TRUE
#  8:   8  2.9 FALSE    2 FALSE
#  9:   9  5.0 FALSE    2 FALSE
# 10:  10  8.0  TRUE    3  TRUE
```

I'm using `magrittr` only to make things readable line-by-line, there is no strict need for it.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment (in case you saw it). I think I finally see what you are trying to do. I think you meant *"filtered-out" stretch greater than 3 **days*** at the start of the answer, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is possibly the least elegant solution possible, but using your example:

```
temp <- dt[,abs(a - shift(a)) >=3]

for(i in 3:length(temp)) {
  if(!(temp[i]|temp[i-1]|temp[i-2])) {
    temp[[i]] <- T
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `data.table` approach

(edit: after reading other answwers, it follows the logic of @shree's data.table approach).

```
#create a column which is TRUE when a changes >= 3
dt[, change_3 := (abs(a - shift(a)) >= 3)]
#create groups based on value the change_3 column
dt[, no_change_gr := rleidv( dt$change_3 ) ]
#create rownumbers within each group of no_change_gr
dt[, no_change_rowid := rowid( no_change_id )]
#mark rownumbers where %%3 == 0 with TRUE
dt[no_change_rowid %% 3 == 0, false_3 := TRUE]
#filter out rows where either change_3 or false_3 is TRUE
dt[ change_3 == TRUE | false_3 == TRUE, .(day,a)][]

#    day    a
# 1:   3 10.0
# 2:   4  2.0
# 3:   7  2.7
# 4:  10  8.0
```

I did not combine rows, so you can view the results of each step.
If the output is as expected, you can merge operations into shorter code (with less lines)